# SetState Flutter causing error : type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, setstate, flutter-provider

I'm using Flutter to make an app, where I want to show a user's purchases and have a button to hide and show a chart regarding the purchases. The whole app is connected to a Firebase Cloud Firestore backend so I use Provider to deal with state management. In the home page (UserPage) whenever I call setState on any variable, without it being linked to anything else I get the error :

> type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was
>
> PurchaseList

I've tried just running a setState function without any code inside, like this:

`onPressed: () {setState(() {});}`

and still get the same error.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'databaseservice.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: StreamProvider<List<User>>.value(
          initialData: [],
          value: DatabaseService('AuthenticaionUID').accountUsers,
          lazy: false,
          child: UserPage(1)),
    );
  }
}

class UserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final int userID;
  UserPage(this.userID);
  @override
  _UserPageState createState() => _UserPageState(userID);
}

class _UserPageState extends State<UserPage> {
  final int userID;
  _UserPageState(this.userID);

  // String error = '';
  bool showChart = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var usersList = Provider.of<List<User>>(context);
    var user;
    usersList.forEach((User userI) {
      if (userI.id == userID) {
        user = userI;
      }
    });

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: Text('${user.name}\'s Budget'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 8, 0),
          // padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: (user.total == 0)
              ? Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: Center(child: Text('No purchases')),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              : Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    showChart
                        ? Container(
                            child: UserChart(user),
                            height: 269,
                          )
                        : Container(),
                    PurchaseList(userID),
                  ],
                )),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.insert_chart),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                showChart = !showChart;
              });
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PurchaseList extends StatelessWidget {
  final int userID;
  PurchaseList(this.userID);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<User> usersList = Provider.of<List<User>>(context);
    User user;
    usersList.forEach((User userI) {
      if (userI.id == userID) {
        user = userI;
      }
    });
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: user.purchases.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Card(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(user.purchases[index]['name']),
                        Text(user.purchases[index]['category']),
                        Text(user.purchases[index]['date']),
                        Text(user.purchases[index]['shop'])
                      ]),
                  // Price
                  Text('\$${user.purchases[index]["price"]}'),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'd really appreciate the help, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Double check your data type in Firebase Console. It could be that your `userID` is a string for example which you compare with `userI.id`. Adding `.toString()` should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So the Error is because the parameter it is expecting is the int value and it is getting the String, check the parameter types or just convert the int to String

Comment: which parameter though, even just calling setState((){}) with no code inside the argument function causes the error

Answer (score 0):

just do this, i retrieved my mobile number which is of int value from firestore

```
Text(document["mobileNo"].toString())
```